# Reverse ip, find domain names on ip address

Tags: dns, whois

How and from where websites like this http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/ are getting this information from? How can I develop such tool?

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/287577/how-to-find-a-domain-based-on-the-ip-address

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use `nslookup` on the IP. Reverse DNS is defined with the `.in-addr.arpa` domain.

Example:

```
nslookup somedomain.com
```

yields `123.21.2.3`, and then you do:

```
nslookup 123.21.2.3
```

this will ask `3.2.21.123.in-addr.arpa` and yield the domain name (if there is one defined for reverse DNS).

Comment: It only displays one domain. Is there a way or parameter to list all the domains pointing to a specific IP address?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ping -a <ip>` or `nbtstat -A <ip>`

Answer (score 8):

They're just trawling lists of web sites, and recording the resulting IP addresses in a database.

All you're seeing is the reverse mapping of that list.  It's not guaranteed to be a full list (indeed more often than not it won't be) because it's impossible to learn every possible web site address.

Answer (score 2):

## windows user can just using the simple `nslookup` command

```
G:\wwwRoot\JavaScript Testing>nslookup 208.97.177.124
Server:  phicomm.me
Address:  192.168.2.1

Name:    apache2-argon.william-floyd.dreamhost.com
Address:  208.97.177.124


G:\wwwRoot\JavaScript Testing>
```

http://www.guidingtech.com/2890/find-ip-address-nslookup-command-windows/

> if you want get more info, please check the following answer!

https://superuser.com/questions/287577/how-to-find-a-domain-based-on-the-ip-address/1177576#1177576

Answer (score 1):

From about section of Reverse IP Domain Check tool on yougetsignal:

> A reverse IP domain check takes a domain name or IP address pointing
>   to a web server and searches for other sites known to be hosted on
>   that same web server. **Data is gathered from search engine results**,
>   which are not guaranteed to be complete.

Comment: Not always. Hoster can change reverse DNS lookup. I would do -1 for that , but i can't. btw, reverse dns used by mail services like google and other.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get domain in intranet

https://gist.github.com/jrothmanshore/2656003

It's a powershell script. Run it in PowerShell

```
.\ip_lookup.ps1 <ip>
```